# change value in a column with apply lambda

Tags: python, dataframe

Do you have a trick to avoid that the following code changes the cells (and keep the existing data) when the condition in the lambda function is not met

```
df['test'] = df['Q8_3'].apply(lambda x: 'serial' if x >=3 else 'toto')
```

This code is running when I add 'toto' after the else statement but I would like to bypass the else statement.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: ```lambda x: 'serial' if x >=3 else x```

Comment: The expected behavior is to keep the value contained in ['test'] not the value x coming from 'Q8_3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this helps you?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Q8_3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'test': ['old','old','old','old','old']
})

df.loc[df.Q8_3 >3 , 'test'] = "serial"
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Q8_3    test
0     1     old
1     2     old
2     3     old
3     4  serial
4     5  serial
```

Comment: The expected behavior is to keep the value contained in ['test'] not the value x coming from 'Q8_3'

Comment: @fredooms you want insert 'serial' on column 'test' if value on column`Q8_3` >3?

Comment: yes this is what I'm looking for :-) More precisely I want to replace the existing value in test by serial if the condition is met

Comment: @fredooms I edited my answer is this your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Or even better with `np.where`:

```
df['test'] = np.where(df['Q8_3'] >= 3, 'serial', df['Q8_3'])
```